# Joomla YJK2Slider Fx issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla-k2, mootools-fx

I've bought an extension to Joomla! from YouJoomla and since their supportforum is the worst thing ever created by man, I thought I would ask you guys instead.

The main issue I have is an Fx problem, or possibly an javascript conflict.

Im trying to add an image slider to K2 objects in Joomla via a plugin called YJK2Slider. The only thing im supposed to have to do is install the plugin, activate it and it should work fine. Yeah, but no. It gets stuck on loading and renders the images 0x0 pixels. However when i remove the code that the console tells me is the conflict it loads the images and I can scroll from left to right, but i cant use the thumbnails which is pretty much a key feature.

This is the complete js code for the slider...

```
var YJK2SimpleSlide = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
    options: {
            outerContainer: null,
            innerContainer: null,
            elements: null,
            navigation: {
                forward: null,
                back: null,
                container: null,
                elements: null,
                outer: null,
                visibleItems: 0
            },
            slideType: 0,
            orientation: 1,
            slideTime: 3000,
            duration: 600,
            tooltips: 0,
            autoslide: 1,
            navInfo: null,
            navLinks: null,
            startElem: null
        },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.setOptions(options);       
        this.navElements = $(this.options.navigation.container).getElements(this.options.navigation.elements);
        this.navScroll = new Fx.Scroll(this.options.navigation.outer, {
            link: 'cancel',
            duration: 800,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut
        });
        this.correction = Math.round(this.options.navigation.visibleItems / 2.00001);
        this.start()
    },

    start: function(){
        this.currentElement = this.options.startElem;   
        this.direction = 1; // -1: back; 1:forward
        this.elements = $(this.options.innerContainer).getElements(this.options.elements);

        this.showEffect = {};
        this.hideEffect = {};
        this.firstRun = {};

        if( this.options.slideType!==0 ){
            if( this.options.orientation == 1 ){
                this.showEffect.left = [1200,0];
                this.hideEffect.left = [0,1200];
                this.firstRun.left = 1200;
            }else{
                this.showEffect.top = [400,0];
                this.hideEffect.top = [0,400];
                this.firstRun.top = 400;
            }
        }
        if( this.options.slideType!==1 ){
            this.showEffect.opacity = [0,1];
            this.hideEffect.opacity = [1,0];
            this.firstRun.opacity = 0;
        }

var fadeSliderIn = new Fx.Morph(this.options.outerContainer, {
    duration: 3000,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
});

fadeSliderIn.start({
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'opacity': [0.001, 1]
}); 
var fadeNavIn = new Fx.Morph(this.options.navigation.container, {
    duration: 3000,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
}); 
fadeNavIn.start({
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'opacity': [0.001, 1]
}); 
        /* slides */
        this.elements.each( function(el, i){            

            el.setStyles({
                'display':'block',
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':0,
                'left':0,
                'z-index':(100-i)
            }); 

            if( this.options.slideType!==1 && i!==this.currentElement  )
                el.setStyle('opacity',0);

            this.elements[i]['fx'] = new Fx.Morph(el, {link:'cancel', duration: this.options.duration});

            if(i!==this.currentElement)
                this.elements[i]['fx'].set(this.firstRun);

            el.addEvent('mouseenter', function(event){
                //$clear(this.period);
                clearTimeout(this.period);
            }.bind(this));
            el.addEvent('mouseleave', function(event){
                if(this.options.autoslide==1){
                    this.resetAutoslide();
                }
            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this));
        /* autoslide on command */
        if(this.options.autoslide == 1){
            this.period = this.rotateSlides.periodical(this.options.slideTime, this);
        }
        /* add navigation */
        this.setNavigation();

        if(this.options.navLinks){
            this.secondNavigation();
            $(this.options.navigation.container).addEvent('mousewheel', function(event){
                event = new Event(event);
                //event.stop();
                event.preventDefault();
                      var dir = event.wheel > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                      var el = this.currentElement - dir;
                //var el = this.currentElement-event.wheel;
                if( event.wheel > 0 && el < 0 ) el = this.navElements.length-1;
                if( event.wheel < 0 && el > this.navElements.length-1 ) el = 0;
                if( this.options.autoslide == 1 ){
                    //$clear(this.period);
                    clearTimeout(this.period);
                    this.resetAutoslide();
                }
                this.nextSlide(el);                 
            }.bind(this));  
        }
    },

    rotateSlides: function(){
        var next = this.currentElement+this.direction;
        if( next < 0 ) next = this.elements.length-1;
        if( next >  this.elements.length-1) next = 0;
        this.nextSlide(next);   
    },

    nextSlide: function(slide){
        if(slide==this.currentElement) return;
        this.elements[this.currentElement]['fx'].start(this.hideEffect);
        this.elements[slide]['fx'].start(this.showEffect);

        this.currentElement = slide;

        if($(this.options.navInfo)){
            $(this.options.navInfo).setHTML('Link '+(slide+1)+' of '+this.elements.length);
        }

        //if($defined(this.navElements)){
        if(this.navElements !== undefined && this.navElements !== null){            
            this.navElements.removeClass('selected');
            this.navElements[slide].addClass('selected');

            /* slide to element */
            var navTo = slide-this.correction < 0 ? 0 : slide-this.correction;  
            if( navTo+this.correction >= this.navElements.length-this.correction ) navTo = (this.navElements.length-1) - this.correction*2;
            this.navScroll.toElement(this.navElements[navTo]);

        }

    },

    setNavigation: function(){
        if(!$(this.options.navigation.forward)) return;

        $(this.options.navigation.forward).addEvent('click', function(event){
            //new Event(event).stop();
            event.preventDefault();
            this.direction = 1;
            if (this.options.autoslide == 1) {
                this.resetAutoslide();  
            }
            this.rotateSlides();
        }.bind(this));

        $(this.options.navigation.back).addEvent('click', function(event){
            //new Event(event).stop();
            event.preventDefault();
            this.direction = -1;
            if (this.options.autoslide == 1) {
                this.resetAutoslide();
            }
            this.rotateSlides();
        }.bind(this));

    },

    resetAutoslide: function(){
        //$clear(this.period);
        clearTimeout(this.period);
        this.period = this.rotateSlides.periodical(this.options.slideTime, this);       
    },

    secondNavigation: function(){
        this.navElements = $$(this.options.navLinks);
        this.navElements.each(function(el,i){

            if( i == this.currentElement ){
                this.navScroll.toElement(el);
                el.addClass('selected');
            }

            el.addEvent('click', function(event){
                //new Event(event).stop();
                event.preventDefault();
                this.resetAutoslide();
                this.nextSlide(i);              
            }.bind(this));

        }.bind(this));

    }
});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   $$('#SimpleSlide_outer').setStyles({
       boxShadow: '0px 0px 3px 1px #d8d8d8',
       WebkitBoxShadow:'0px 0px 3px 1px #d8d8d8',
       MozBoxShadow:'0px 0px 3px 1px #d8d8d8'
    });
});
```

...and this is the parts that screwes it up.

```
this.navScroll = new Fx.Scroll(this.options.navigation.outer, {
            link: 'cancel',
            duration: 800,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut
        });
```

Heres a link to where i want to put the slider; http://dev9.hosterspace.com/pyramiden/index.php/projekt/utbildning/item/4-campus-varberg
And heres the developers demo site; http://extensions.youjoomla.info/yj-k2-image-slider.html

Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: TypeError: Fx.Scroll is not a constructor
[Break On This Error]  

transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut -- that is what the debugger says. Do you have the right version of Mootools?

Comment: I believe you are using version 1.0 of the plugin and the latest version is 1.0.2. Try updating the plugin to see if this solves the issue

Comment: @philipp , I have the same Mootools version as the developer has on their demo page, do you know which version it should be so I can doublecheck?

Comment: @Lodder , I checked the version and I have 1.0.5. It could be something wrong with it though, Ill check if I can get an earlier version!

Comment: Solved it guys, by some reason mootools-more didnt get included! Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my Joomla! installation did not include mootools-more.js which should be included by default. When i added it things worked swimmingly!